# 'Expected String or Unicode' when reading JSON with Pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas, openstreetmap, overpass-api

I try to read an [Openstreetmaps API](http://overpass-api.de/api/convert?data=%3C!--%0AThis%20has%20been%20generated%20by%20the%20overpass-turbo%20wizard.%0AThe%20original%20search%20was%3A%0A%E2%80%9CBushaltestelle%E2%80%9D%0A--%3E%0A%3Cosm-script%20output%3D%22json%22%20timeout%3D%2225%22%3E%0A%20%20%3C!--%20gather%20results%20--%3E%0A%20%20%3Cunion%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C!--%20query%20part%20for%3A%20%E2%80%9CBushaltestelle%E2%80%9D%20--%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cquery%20type%3D%22node%22%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Chas-kv%20k%3D%22highway%22%20v%3D%22bus_stop%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cbbox-query%20s%3D%2250.973778188690716%22%20w%3D%2213.552322387695312%22%20n%3D%2251.12033393562918%22%20e%3D%2213.898735046386719%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2Fquery%3E%0A%20%20%3C%2Funion%3E%0A%20%20%3C!--%20print%20results%20--%3E%0A%20%20%3Cprint%20mode%3D%22body%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Crecurse%20type%3D%22down%22%2F%3E%0A%20%20%3Cprint%20mode%3D%22skeleton%22%20order%3D%22quadtile%22%2F%3E%0A%3C%2Fosm-script%3E&target=compact) output [JSON](http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter?data=%5Bout%3Ajson%5D%5Btimeout%3A25%5D%3B%28node%5B%22highway%22%3D%22bus_stop%22%5D%2850%2E973778188690716%2C13%2E552322387695312%2C51%2E12033393562918%2C13%2E898735046386719%29%3B%29%3Bout%20body%3B%3E%3Bout%20skel%20qt%3B) string, which is valid.

I am using following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

# Links unten
minLat = 50.9549
minLon = 13.55232

# Rechts oben
maxLat = 51.1390
maxLon = 13.89873

osmrequest = {'data': '[out:json][timeout:25];(node["highway"="bus_stop"](%s,%s,%s,%s););out body;>;out skel qt;' % (minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon)}
osmurl = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter'
osm = requests.get(osmurl, params=osmrequest)

osmdata = osm.json()

osmdataframe = pd.read_json(osmdata)
```

which throws following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-66-304b7fbfb645> in <module>()
----> 1 osmdataframe = pd.read_json(osmdata)

/Users/paul/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in read_json(path_or_buf, orient, typ, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates, keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float, date_unit)
    196         obj = FrameParser(json, orient, dtype, convert_axes, convert_dates,
    197                           keep_default_dates, numpy, precise_float,
--> 198                           date_unit).parse()
    199 
    200     if typ == 'series' or obj is None:

/Users/paul/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in parse(self)
    264 
    265         else:
--> 266             self._parse_no_numpy()
    267 
    268         if self.obj is None:

/Users/paul/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/io/json.pyc in _parse_no_numpy(self)
    481         if orient == "columns":
    482             self.obj = DataFrame(
--> 483                 loads(json, precise_float=self.precise_float), dtype=None)
    484         elif orient == "split":
    485             decoded = dict((str(k), v)

TypeError: Expected String or Unicode
```

How to modify the request or Pandas `read_json`, to avoid an error? By the way, what's the problem?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you print the json string to a file,

```
content = osm.read()
with open('/tmp/out', 'w') as f:
    f.write(content)
```

you'll see something like this:

```
{
  "version": 0.6,
  "generator": "Overpass API",
  "osm3s": {
    "timestamp_osm_base": "2014-07-20T07:52:02Z",
    "copyright": "The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL."
  },
  "elements": [

{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 536694,
  "lat": 50.9849256,
  "lon": 13.6821776,
  "tags": {
    "highway": "bus_stop",
    "name": "Niederhäslich Bergmannsweg"
  }
},
...]}
```

If the JSON string were to be converted to a Python object, it would be a dict whose `elements` key is a list of dicts. The vast majority of the data is inside this list of dicts.

This JSON string is not directly convertible to a Pandas object. What would be the index, and what would be the columns? 
Surely you don't want `[u'elements', u'version', u'osm3s', u'generator']` to be the columns, since almost all the information is in the `elements` list-of-dicts.

But if you want the DataFrame to consist of the data only in the `elements` list-of-dicts, then you'd have to specify that, since Pandas can't make that assumption for you.

Further complicating things is that each dict in `elements` is a nested dict. Consider the first dict in `elements`:

```
{
  "type": "node",
  "id": 536694,
  "lat": 50.9849256,
  "lon": 13.6821776,
  "tags": {
    "highway": "bus_stop",
    "name": "Niederhäslich Bergmannsweg"
  }
}
```

Should `['lat', 'lon', 'type', 'id', 'tags']` be the columns? 
That seems plausible, except that the `tags` column would end up being a column of dicts. That's usually not very useful. It would be nicer perhaps if the keys inside the `tags` dict were made into columns. We can do that, but again we have to code it ourselves since Pandas has no way of knowing that's what we want.

---

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
# Links unten
minLat = 50.9549
minLon = 13.55232

# Rechts oben
maxLat = 51.1390
maxLon = 13.89873

osmrequest = {'data': '[out:json][timeout:25];(node["highway"="bus_stop"](%s,%s,%s,%s););out body;>;out skel qt;' % (minLat, minLon, maxLat, maxLon)}
osmurl = 'http://overpass-api.de/api/interpreter'
osm = requests.get(osmurl, params=osmrequest)

osmdata = osm.json()
osmdata = osmdata['elements']
for dct in osmdata:
    for key, val in dct['tags'].iteritems():
        dct[key] = val
    del dct['tags']

osmdataframe = pd.DataFrame(osmdata)
print(osmdataframe[['lat', 'lon', 'name']].head())
```

yields

```
         lat        lon                        name
0  50.984926  13.682178  Niederhäslich Bergmannsweg
1  51.123623  13.782789                Sagarder Weg
2  51.065752  13.895734     Weißig, Einkaufszentrum
3  51.007140  13.698498          Stuttgarter Straße
4  51.010199  13.701411          Heilbronner Straße
```

Comment: Great explanation!! I understand this perfectly, but couldn't solve the riddle for my own. Thanks!

In the line `osmdata = json.loads(osm.read())` might be something not correct, because I get: `AttributeError: 'Response' object has no attribute 'read'`

Comment: It have to be `osmdata = json.loads(osm.content)`

Comment: @Balzer82: My version of requests was too old; the API has changed since then. I've updated by `requests` and will edit the code above.